# Linear order cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Could you please help me with this question from elementary set theory exam.

Suppose R is linear order on some unfinite set A.

Prove that $|R|=|A|$.

My attempt:

$R\subseteq A\times A$, so $|R|\le|A|$.

How to prove that $|R|\ge|A|$ ?

I suppose that there exists some bijectional function from R onto A, but how to construct one ?

Edit: R is non-reflexive,transitive and complete order on A, $|A|\ge\aleph_0$.

Thank you.

Comment: $|R|\ge|A|$ holds for any reflexive relation $R$ on any set $A$.

Comment: In my book, linear order defined as non-reflexive.

Comment: Your book must have an odd definition of linear order. For example, in $1 \leq 2 \leq 3 \leq 4$ there is definitely more than $4$ relations (even if we do not count the reflexive relations), we have $1 \leq 2$, $1 \leq 3$, $1 \leq 4$, $2 \leq 3$, $2 \leq 4$ and $3 \leq 4$.

Comment: @Mark That's where we need that $A$ is infinite, or *unfinite*, as it's called in the OP.

Comment: @Vsotvep Ah, I read finite.  Probably still thinking about an earlier question from OP. I'll leave my comment as an example why the infinity of $A$ is a necessary assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $a \in A$. As $R$ is a linear order, it contains either $(x, a)$ or $(a,x)$ for all $x \in A$.

Comment: For all $x\in A\setminus \{a\}$

Comment: Yes, mathecounterexamples.net is right. Since $R$ is a linear order, for every $x\in A$, there must exists a fixed $a\in A$ such that $(x, a)$ or $(a, x)$ in $R$ such that $|A|\leq |R|$.

Comment: @gete See the discussion above, the linear order is defined to be non-reflexive. Otherwise the suggestion that bof gives is an even easier injection.